# Multi-tasking for loop on discord on_message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, multiprocessing

Hello and thank you in advance to whoever wants to help me.

This is the first time I use the multiprocessing module and my goal is to multitask a for loop on an on_message function from discord.py.

I got an error at "process.start()" who say :

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.scrapeall'←[0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Here's some of my code I'm struggling with (everything else works fine) :

```
def main():
    def scrapeall(unit, idx, name, nom, sk, photo):
        if Counter(name[:idx+1])[unit]==1:
            nom[idx]=scrapename(unit)
            if nom[idx].startswith("BUY"):
                skname=""
                urlimg=""
            else:
                with open("[...]/historic.csv","r",newline='') as incsv:
                    [...]
        if Counter(name[:idx+1])[unit]>1:
            indexfirst=name.index(unit)
            nom[idx]=nom[indexfirst]
            skname=sku[indexfirst]
            urlimg=photo[indexfirst]
        sk[idx]=skname
        photo[idx]=urlimg

    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        [...]
        processes= [Process(target=scrapeall, args=(unit, idx, name, nom, sk, photo)) for idx,unit in enumerate(name)]
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

    bot.run(TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All my work is in main() to don't let the multiprocessing re-run all my code everytime he start.
I'm not sure if enumerate() can be use like this.
For information, my scrapename() module scrape a google page and that's why I need multiprocessing to be faster in my for loop.

Thanks in advance

I expect the multitasking of my for loop in an on_message (bot.event) from discord.py module.

Comment: Why are you using processes instead of threads? Doesn't seem to be necessary, it's not a really CPU heavy task. Also, you cannot call `process.join`, it will block your whole event loop and the bot won't work. I can help you and write an answer, but I gotta understand why are you using processes.

Comment: It's because my scrapename() module web scrape an image (in every element of the for loop), and if I understood correctly, for this kind of thing multi-threading is less suitable than multi-processing.